# Click event in HorizontalListView relates to wrong View

Tags: android

OK, this is a long shot but here it goes anyways:

I'm using a customized `HorizontalListView` in my app based on [this](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView/blob/master/AndroidHorizontalListView/src/com/meetme/android/horizontallistview/HorizontalListView.java) one. In `Adapter.getView()` i add a ClickListener to the View.

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = mInflater.inflate(...);
    v.addOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));
    return v;
}
```

This is much simplified, of course i do much more there. Now what happens sometimes when i scroll like crazy left and right and then click an item, is that the wrong position is outputted - only the first time though. The second click shows the correct position. The position that i see is not even from a recycled View, it's from one like 2 positions next to the clicked one.

I suspect a timing issue in the Looper, since there is quite some stuff going on there. Something like the click position gets recorded, then the `HorizontalListView` removes some invisible views and then the clicked view gets wrongly evaluated. But that's only a guess.

Funny thing is, when i use the `onItmeClicked()` event on the `HorizontalListView`, i always get the correct position.

Has anyone ever experienced something similar and could point me in the right direction where to look?

**Edit:**

I also tried to output the position of the clicked view and it is definitely not the one that i've clicked, but the one 2 positions to the left. But as I said, that happens only every once in a while.

Comment: Is it easy to try and reproduce it with a normal `ListView`? Perhaps the `HorizontalListView` messes things up.

Comment: I have never had this problem with a normal `ListView`

Comment: You also say your implementation is based on that HorizontalListView. Does the problem occur on the original one as well?